# bada Programming - Close (overlay) Keypad Without ScrollPanel

Tags: c++, bada, keypad

I am new to bada programming. I have a question that is, is it possible to close the overlay keypad used by the editfield without implementing the scrollpanel? I know it is possible to use CloseOverlayWindow(); method, but this is only application for scrollpanel. Are there any alternatives to close the keypad besides implementing the scrollpanel?

Thanks all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by using:

```
pEditfield->HideKeypad();
```